# Parse between quotes with Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, megaparsec

The requirements are taken from the [DOT language specification](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/lang.html), more precisely I'm trying to parse the `[ID]` attribute, which can be e.g.,

> any double-quoted string ("...") possibly containing escaped quotes (\")1;

The following should be a minimal example.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import           Text.Megaparsec
import           Text.Megaparsec.Char
import           Data.Void
import           Data.Char
import           Data.Text               hiding ( map
                                        , all
                                        , concat
                                        )

type Parser = Parsec Void Text

escape :: Parser String
escape = do
    d <- char '\\'
    c <- oneOf ['\\', '\"', '0', 'n', 'r', 'v', 't', 'b', 'f']
    return [d, c]

nonEscape :: Parser Char
nonEscape = noneOf ['\\', '\"', '\0', '\n', '\r', '\v', '\t', '\b', '\f']

identPQuoted :: Parser String
identPQuoted =
    let inner = fmap return (try nonEscape) <|> escape
    in  do
      char '"'
      strings <- many inner
      char '"'
      return $ concat strings

identP :: Parser Text
identP = identPQuoted >>= return . pack

main = parseTest identP "\"foo \"bar\""
```

The above code fails on the second with returns `"foo "` even though I want `foo "bar`

I don't understand why. I thought that `megaparsec` would repeatedly apply `inner` until it parses the final `"`. But it only repeatedly applies the `nonEscape` parser and the first time that fails, and it uses `escape`, it then appears to skip the rest of the inner string and just move on to the final quotes.

Comment: `>>= return .` can be replaced by `<$>`: `identP = pack <$> identPQuoted`

Comment: The `do` block in `identPQuoted` can be written as `char '"' *> (concat <$> many inner) <* char '"'`

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? I'd like to try this myself.

Comment: The requirement is rather poorly worded. Can you show a real grammar of your input language? Also, try `reads`.

Comment: I added an example @melpomene and updated the requirements

Comment: A list of characters like `['\\', '\"', '0', 'n', 'r', 'v', 't', 'b', 'f']` can be written more conveniently and compactly as a `String` literal like `"\\\"0nrvtbf"`, since `type String = [Char]`

Comment: Warning: the list of characters in `nonEscape` is a list of *single characters*, i.e. `\n` is a literal newline character, `\0` is the null character (which you would never see in a plain text file).  Probably not what you meant.

Comment: @luqui That part looks fine to me. It says double-quoted strings cannot contain literal control characters (such as NUL, newline, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input text is `"foo "bar"`, which does not contain any escaped quotes. It is parsed as a complete ID of `"foo "` (followed by `bar"`, which is ignored).

If you want to make sure that your parser consumes all of the available input, you can use

```
parseTest (identP <* eof) "..."
```

If you want to provide an ID with an escaped quote to the parser, like this ...

```
"foo \"bar"
```

... then you need to escape all of the special characters to embed them in Haskell source code:

```
main = parseTest identP "\"foo \\\"bar\""
```

`\"` represents a literal `"` and `\\` represents a literal `\`.

Comment: Thanks! Kind of embarrassing in hindsight.